# Crystal Report Running Totals

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I need to customize running total in crystal report

[image: Sample Report]

Following I show my evaluation formula of Running total

```
If {spPet_DailySummery;1.HPetVouNo} = {spPet_DailySummery;1.HPetVouNo} Then
    True
```

Following I show my reset formula of Running Total

```
If Previous({spPet_DailySummery;1.HPetVouNo}) <> {spPet_DailySummery;1.HPetVouNo} then
    True
Else
    False
```

Someone, please let me know how can I got report as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the steps below which worked for me**

1. Group you report by V/No it will create Footer

   [image: enter code here]
2. Insert summery

   [image: enter code here]
3. Add Running Total

   [image: enter code here]
4. Right Click on running total go to formate object

   [image: enter code here]
5. now suppress your footer group sum field

   [image: enter code here]
6. This has been tested and confirmed on my local machine.

Comment: Thanks!, its pleasure for me to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow Steps I don it**

1. Group you report by V/No it will create Footer

   [image: enter code here]
2. Insert summery

   [image: enter code here]
3. Add Running Total

   [image: enter code here]
4. Right Click on running total go to formate object

   [image: enter code here]
5. now suppress your footer group sum field

   [image: enter code here]